# Is it possible to set some kind of interfaces for enums?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a use case where I need to declare several text enums with the same keys, like:

```
enum Title {
  ScreenA = 'screen A text',
  ScreenB = 'screen B text',
}

enum Content {
  ScreenA = 'Content A text',
  ScreenB = 'Content B text',
}
```

those Enums are used in an Angular template.

Is it possible to create some kind of interface to assure that when a new screen comes all the enums ask for it?

What I want:

```
SomeKindOfInterfaceForMyEnum {
  ScreenA: string,
  ScreenB: string,
  ScreenC: string,
}

enum Content uses SomeKindOfInterfaceForMyEnum  { ///<-- ERROR ScreenC is required
  ScreenA = 'Content A text',
  ScreenB = 'Content B text',
}
```

Comment: Why do you need an `interface` for an `enum`? Be definition, an `enum` is a set of readonly/constant values, so you can directly use them in your Angular template. Btw, the way you are creating your enum is wrong: check out the typescript docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums

Comment: @Eastrall It is used as a mapping for translations in the project where I have to work right now. And yes, I just wrote the code here directly. I will correct them

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [@Eastrall idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58483235/1255819) as base for the final solution using an interface.

Declare an interface:

```
SomeKindOfInterfaceForMyEnum {
  ScreenA: string,
  ScreenB: string,
  ScreenC: string,
}
```

Use a const instead of an string enum.

```
const Content: SomeKindOfInterfaceForMyEnum  = { 
  ScreenA: 'Content A text',
  ScreenB: 'Content B text',
// <-- asks for ScreenC
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There a some solutions to achieve what you want to do, which is: extending an enum.
There is actually an issue on GitHub that gives a lot a workarounds: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17592

One of the solutions would be to **not use** `enum` but use something that **looks like** an `enum` (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17592#issuecomment-375968511)

```
const BasicEvents = {
  Start: 'Start' as 'Start',
  Finish: 'Finish' as 'Finish'
};
type BasicEvents = (typeof BasicEvents)[keyof typeof BasicEvents];

const AdvEvents = {
  ...BasicEvents,
  Pause: 'Pause' as 'Pause',
  Resume: 'Resume' as 'Resume'
};
type AdvEvents = (typeof AdvEvents)[keyof typeof AdvEvents];
```

And other solution, would be to use a class with `readonly` variables that will contain you translation keys. Then you can use the `extends` keyword.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem I have is no in how to use in the template but how to make it more extensible. Check at my edit. Sorry I was not clear.